# How to push ETCD keys into Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, etcd

From my application, I generate some events which are stored in etcd as /events/ keys.

I want these events to push to prometheus. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try to forward `data logs` to `prometheus` via `middleware`?

Answer (score 0):

You can track how often these events are occurring with Prometheus but your use case here suggests that you want to do event logging.

Comment: Yes, I want to push the metrics myself to Prometheus, stored in the ETCD key value pairs. How can I achieve that?